# Is it possible to share a _Layout.cshtml between razor pages and MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

Suppose I have a .net 5.0 website that has both Razor pages and MVC pages.

That is, in Startup.Configure, I have:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

And I have some pages like:

- /Pages/MyRazorPage.cshtml
- /Pages/MyRazorPage.cshtml.cs

And others like:

- /Controllers/MyMvcController.cs
- /Views/MyMvc/Index.cshtml

Is there a way to have them use the same layout?

It seems simple enough to create a Razor layout in /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml and another in /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml, but if you want to have identical layouts for both types of pages, this seems a violation of the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.

Is there a way of sharing a single layout between both types of page?

---

Just as a followup - copying /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml to /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml (and making sure /Views/_ViewStart.cshtml is set) works, except that the asp-page helpers don't work. Setting the URLs with plain href= works fine.

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes,it is possible.For example,you have a layout in `/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.And you want to set the layout in views with it.
Change `Views/Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml` like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

So that both the layouts in Pages and Views will be `/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.